# Why won't my for-loop start in some cases?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, division

I've written som simple code in javascript which let's you input a starting and ending value for an interval and specify a denominator. After the input the program will go trough the interval and check how many of the numbers are divisible by the specified denominator.

It seemed to work just fine at first, but in some cases the program won't run the loop at all, and I have a hard time figuring out why.

My code:

```
//declarations
var startValue = prompt ("pick a starting value:");
var endValue = prompt ("pick an ending value:");
var divide = prompt ("pick a denominator");
var count = 0;

//control divisibility
for (startValue; startValue <= endValue; startValue++) {
 var quotient = startValue/divide;
  if (quotient % 1 == 0) {
   count++; 
  }
}

//result
alert("There are " + count + " numbers divisible by " + divide + " in the interval");
```

Below are some input values that has worked/not worked with the program
(shown as "startNr, endNr, divide"):

Working:
3, 92, 8
1, 100, 1
17, 200, 12
24, 379, 22
18, 90, 18

Not Working:
5, 25, 5
7, 21, 7
2, 108, 8

Thanks.

Comment: Do it have any console failed log?

Comment: You are comparing strings not integers that's your problem it's not 5 it '5'

Comment: To check if a `number` is divisible by `divide`, use this expression: `number % divide == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `prompt` returns the input as a **string**, and you do not convert it to number.

When you compare strings, lexicographical ordering is applied, and based on such ordering, for example, `"25"` comes before `"5"`

```js
console.log("25" < "5");
```

So you should replace your declarations with:

```
var startValue = Number(prompt ("pick a starting value:"));
var endValue = Number(prompt ("pick an ending value:"));
var divide = Number(prompt ("pick a denominator"));
```

As a side note, since you divide by `divide`, you should also check it is not zero!

Or, even better, instead of performing an actual division and then a check on the quotient, just do as @hindmost suggests:

```
for (startValue; startValue <= endValue; startValue++) {
  if (startValue % divide == 0) {
   count++; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great first impression of Stack Overflow :)